# How to remove String null in android

Tags: android, substring

I want to remove String null and want to show like this `Item 1, Item2, Item 3` Here is output... `nullItem 1Item 2Item 3`

```
    String result;
    for (Cuisine c : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (c.checkbox) {
            result += c.name;
        }
    }
    // result = result.substring(0,4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your String like this:

```
String result = "";
```

instead of just:

```
String result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're appending the three `box` names to an initially `null` String (result) , solve this problem by making your String an  empty string at the beginning :

```
String result = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, put a null check.

```
String result;
for (Cuisine c : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
    if (c.checkbox) {
        if(c.name != null)
            result += c.name;
    }
}
```

OR

You can just initialize your String with empty string like:-

```
String result = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

```
String result;
        for (Cuisine c : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
            if ((c.name!=null)&&(c.checkbox)) {
                result += c.name;
            }
        }
        //
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as it is the `null` value of `result` that we see not an `null` value from `c.name`

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expression to replace non-printable characters.

```
String string=line.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","");
```